# To update rows in another table based on selected output from another table, but program only update top one row

Tags: java, android-studio, jdbc, sql-update, rows

I want to update multiple rows from table 'WORKTR' based on the selected rows from table 'BRTR'. Unfortunately, the program only update the WORKTR table based on the top one row from 'BRTR' table.

Here is my code:

```
      Button Back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_back);
        Back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                connectionClass = new ConnectionClass();
                Connection con = connectionClass.CONN();
                try {
                    final String PIC = lblname.getText().toString();
                    String dates = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH).format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
                    String check = "Select * from BRTR where work_date='" + dates + "' and end_break is null";
                    Statement st = con.createStatement();

                    rs = st.executeQuery(check);


                    while (rs.next()) {
                        String PF_NO = rs.getString("PF_No");



                        String query2 = "Update WORKTR set status ='" + b_status + "' where Start_date='" + dates + "' and Pf_no='" + PF_NO + "' and Scan_by='" + PIC + "' and status='" + a_status + "'";

                        st.executeUpdate(query2);
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex)
                {

                }
                onBackPressed();
            }

        });
```

Please help or notify if you see any mistakes from the codes above.

Answer (score 0):

Try using another statement since `st.executeUpdate(query2);` will close the ResultSet and you will get `JdbcSQLException` however you ignore all the exceptions on your code. You should at least put `ex.printStackTrace()` to your catch block so you can see what is going on.

Eventhough code-wise there are a lot to improve here, functionally this should work for you,

```
      Button Back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_back);
    Back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            connectionClass = new ConnectionClass();
            Connection con = connectionClass.CONN();
            try {
                final String PIC = lblname.getText().toString();
                String dates = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH).format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
                String check = "Select * from BRTR where work_date='" + dates + "' and end_break is null";
                Statement st = con.createStatement();

                rs = st.executeQuery(check);


                while (rs.next()) {
                    String PF_NO = rs.getString("PF_No");



                    String query2 = "Update WORKTR set status ='" + b_status + "' where Start_date='" + dates + "' and Pf_no='" + PF_NO + "' and Scan_by='" + PIC + "' and status='" + a_status + "'";

                    con.createStatement().executeUpdate(query2);
                }
            } catch (Exception ex)
            {
               ex.printStackTrace(); // now we can see what is going wrong
            }
            onBackPressed();
        }

    });
```